# Laravel API routes not working in production but work in dev environment

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nginx, amazon-ec2

My front-end is in Vue 3, and my API is in Laravel. My application works fine in the local system, but only web routes work in the production environment, not API routes, giving a 404 error. SPA and API are in a single project hosted on EC2 using the Nginx web server.

**api.php**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PasswordController;

Route::post('register', [AuthController::class,'register']);
Route::post('login', [AuthController::class,'login']);
Route::post('forgot', [PasswordController::class,'forgot']);
Route::post('reset', [PasswordController::class,'reset']);
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function (){
Route::get('user',[AuthController::class,'user']);
Route::post('logout',[AuthController::class,'logout']);
});
```

**web.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '^(?!api\/)[\/\w\.\,-]*');
```

**Nginx config file**

[image: nginx config file]

Comment: Do you have the public root set to `/public` ? Also note that Laravel ships with an Apache .htaccess file that sends requests to index.php - NGINX won't support that you'll have to handle that differently.

Comment: Thank you ahoffner, yes it is set to /public

Comment: NGINX doesn't support then what option do I have

Answer (score 0):

Are you clear route cache in your production ?

```
php artisan route:clear
```